# MongoDB add an index for unknown fields

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I am using MongoDB to store various types of objects everything is in one collection all objects conform to a similar type. Fields are custom per type of object stored. Field type values can be text, integer, or float.

```
{
    objectTypeId: x,
    fields: [
        { fieldTypeId: "x1", fieldName: "fieldX1", fieldValue: "x1" },
        { fieldTypeId: "x2", fieldName: "fieldX2", fieldValue: "x2" }
    ]
}

{
    objectTypeId: y,
    fields: [
        { fieldTypeId: "y1", fieldName: "fieldY1", fieldValue: "y1" },
        { fieldTypeId: "y2", fieldName: "fieldY2", fieldValue: "y2" }
    ]
}
```

Is there a way to add a generic index that would index all of my field data something like:

```
db.records.createIndex( { fields.fieldName: field.fieldValue } );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create index using `db.records.createIndex( { fieldName:1, fieldValue:1 } );` You specify the index to the field, not to the value.

Comment: It must be other way round: `{ fieldValue:1, fieldName:1 }`. If I get the question, OP want to have an index by fieldName for elements of fields where fieldValue = "y2" for example.

Comment: @AlexBlex, what is the difference between `{ fieldValue:1, fieldName:1 }` and  `{ fieldName:1, fieldValue:1 }` ?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. The question is to index by fieldValue, where fieldName="fieldY1". The difference is in sort prefix: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/#use-indexes-to-sort-query-results